# Redux - mapDispatchToProps - TypeError: _this.props.setCurrentUserHandle is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to get a simple react-redux app to work and I am running into a weird error that I can't figure out.  I am trying to simply set my current user's first name and handle the store and one set function works and the other doesn't.

setCurrentUserFirstName - works
setCurrentUserHandle - doesn't

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../../store';
var Utilities = require('../../../common/commonutilities.js');
var RestClient = require('../../../common/restClient.js');

//actions
import { setCurrentUserHandle, setCurrentUserFirstName } from '../../actions/userActions';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};

    RestClient.api.fetchGet('/getcurrentuser', (response) => {
      if(response.success) {
        this.setState({
          isAuthenticated: true,
          currentUser: response.currentUser
        });

        store.dispatch({
          type: 'USER_DID_LOGIN',
          userLoggedIn: true
        });

        //works fine
        this.props.setCurrentUserFirstName(response.currentUser.firstName);      

        //doesn't work and throws the error: "TypeError: _this.props.setCurrentUserHandle is not a function"
        this.props.setCurrentUserHandle(response.currentUser.handle);

      }
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      

        {this.props.user.currentUserFirstName}, {this.props.user.currentUserHandle}

      

    );
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
  return {

         //user properties
         user: store.userState
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

      return{
        setCurrentUserFirstName: (currentUserFirstName) =>{
          dispatch(  setCurrentUserFirstName(currentUserFirstName));
        }
      }

      return{
        setCurrentUserHandle: (currentUserHandle) =>{
          dispatch(  setCurrentUserHandle(currentUserHandle));
        }
      }     

};


//connect it all
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

I have them as actions in the userActions.js file

```js
export function  setCurrentUserFirstName(currentUserFirstName){
    return{
            type:  'SET_CURRENT_USER_FIRST_NAME',
            payload: currentUserFirstName
    };      
}


export function  setCurrentUserHandle(currentUserHandle){
    return{
            type: 'SET_CURRENT_USER_HANDLE',
            payload: currentUserHandle
    };      
}
```

And in the reducer

```js
const initialUserState = {
  user: {}, 
  currentUserFirstName:[],
  currentUserHandle:[]
};

// The User reducer
const userReducer = (state = initialUserState, action) => {

  //using newState object to be immutable
        let newState = state;

        switch (action.type) {

          case 'SET_CURRENT_USER_FIRST_NAME':
                newState = {
                  ...state,   
                  currentUserFirstName:  action.payload 
            };
            break;

          case 'SET_CURRENT_USER_HANDLE':
                newState = {
                  ...state,   
                  currentUserHandle:  action.payload
            };
            break;

            break;

          default:
        break;
  }

  return newState;
};

export default userReducer;
```

What do I have incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 return statements in your `mapDispatchToProps` - the second one will never be reached. You can return a single object as follows:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return{
        setCurrentUserFirstName: (currentUserFirstName) =>{
          dispatch(  setCurrentUserFirstName(currentUserFirstName));
        },
        setCurrentUserHandle: (currentUserHandle) =>{
          dispatch(  setCurrentUserHandle(currentUserHandle));
        }
      }  
};
```

Comment: concise, quick, perfect.  Thank you.  I knew it was something small that I missed.

Comment: This can be simplified even more by removing the unnecessary `return`. If an arrow function has only a single statement this will implicitly be taken as the return value: `mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({/* properties here */});`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tony's correct answer, I highly encourage that you use the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch` instead.  You can pass an object full of action creators as the second argument to `connect()`, instead of an actual `mapDispatch` function.  In your case, it'd look like:

```
import { setCurrentUserHandle, setCurrentUserFirstName } from '../../actions/userActions';

const actionCreators =  { setCurrentUserHandle, setCurrentUserFirstName };

class Header extends Component {}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(Header);
```